# My project got Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: java, android, react-native

**Hi guys !**
I create my React native app using code `npx react-native init projectname`
and run my project with `npx react-native start` then `npx react-native run-android`, but after installing gradle and compiling it seems error

> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)".
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.2 in
> /home/dude/Android/Sdk/build-tools/30.0.2 "Install Android SDK
> Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)" complete. "Install Android SDK
> Build-Tools 30.0.2 (revision: 30.0.2)" finished.
>
> > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED 26 actionable tasks: 26 executed
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 contains a valid JDK installation.
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug
> -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
> > Could not find tools.jar. Please check that /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64 contains a valid JDK installation.

**What ive been tried**
Reinstall JDK.
Install JDK 11.
Find tool.jar manually which i couldnt find anywhere or i dont know how to find it.
find answer in help.gradle.com and stackoverflow.

Thanks before
Russ